# Pressure switch short cycles only when running water. No leaks

Tags: well, well-pump

Replaced my pressure switch now the pressure drops from 60 to
40 in 5 seconds when running water.  When water is off the system is tight with no leaks or psi drop.

Comment: what's your exact question? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Look up water logged pressure tank.  Your bladder is busted or you do not have any air left in the tank if it is non bladder type.

Answer (score 2):

Your pressure tank has failed, and you need a new one. It's full of water and has little-to-no air space in it. The constant pump starts will destroy your pump soon if you don't fix it.

You can kludge a temporary improvement by pumping air into the tank, but you'll need a new tank as the bladder holding the air apart from the water has failed (unless you have the "highly unlikely in the past 40 years" old-style no-bladder tank, in which case you need to fix the snifter valve, or replace the tank with a modern bladder or diaphragm tank.)

With the water pressure at 0, (pump off, water drained) there should be 37-38 PSI air in the tank bladder for a 60-40 switch setting. You can try to drain and pump it up, but it would be *very* surprising if that was possible, given your symptoms. With a leaking bladder you are generally limited to adding air with the water side pressurized, and it's never going to be exact, nor will it it stay solved for any length of time. But if you add air until the pump runs for at least 60 seconds that will improve the odds of only needing to replace the tank, rather than needing to replace the tank **and** pump.